# How to disable ehcache in persistence.xml file

Tags: hibernate, spring, web-applications, ehcache, second-level-cache

All,
is it possible to disable secondary cache in my persistence xml file?
I have a Spring+Hibernate+JPA configuration that uses ehcache. In my persistence.xml file I have this entry:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
```

but this does not seem to work, and I still see the number of entities loaded keeps on increasing, as my application runs. I fetch the statistics using this:

```
EntityManagerFactoryInfo emfi = (EntityManagerFactoryInfo) entityManagerFactory;
EntityManagerFactory emf = emfi.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
EntityManagerFactoryImpl empImpl = (EntityManagerFactoryImpl)emf;
log.debug(empImpl.getSessionFactory().getStatistics());
```

Please help.

Comment: Which statistics are you looking at? Because this property should do what you want, and the number of entities loaded have nothing to do with the second-level cache. Look at all the methods in Statistics starting with getSecondLevelCache

Comment: I am looking at this statistics: "entities loaded=30"

Comment: The number of entities loaded is the number of entities loaded in the session, i.e. the first-level cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statistics you are looking at is the Hibernate session cache (the 1st level cache). Your 2nd level cache (ehcache) is disabled. What you experience is the normal behaviour.

EDIT:

When ehcache is enabled you would find log entries like:

```
[#|...|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory|...|Second-level cache: enabled|#]
[#|...|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory|...|Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider|#]
```

(provided you enable logging for the package - the cache provider may vary e.g. maybe `net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory` - don't know what you use)

Comment: is there any log that suggests that the ehcache is disabled? How do I confirm that the ehcache is actually disables and how do I find what are the entities that are served from ehcahce and not the hibernate 1st level cache?

Comment: @Ayusman: added infos about what ehcache logs; as JB Nizet suggested you can also look at the getSecondLevelCache*() methods of the `Statistics` object you get from `empImpl.getSessionFactory().getStatistics()`